# what's the phrase for "I don't want to be reliant on someone else"

Tags: phrases, vocabulary, phrase-requests, expressions, word-phrases

I remember that there is a phrase with the word `whims` that goes about like this: "I don't want to be reliant on someone else"

Does anyone know what that phrase is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most often used not to express reliance but that someone is bound to carry out someone else's wishes, however trivial they may be.  I can't think of a set phrase but it may help you to know that the most common collocation (after *a*) is with *every*.  Here are some examples from COCA:

> ...a smiling wife more than happy to cater to his every whim.
>
> ...a polished wait staff tends to your every whim.
>
> Why do you have to indulge his every whim?

I didn't notice you were after the plural *whims*, in this case there is a phrase *subject to the whims of*, for example:

> Fruit blossoms are famously subject to the whims of weather

Comment: "subject to the whims of" is what i'm looking for . thx

Answer (score 2):

Here is one:

> I don't want to be a slave to the whims of others.

Comment: There is something with your answer.

Comment: Or, *I don't want to be at the mercy of someone else's whims*.